# Ejecute mi proyecto y se oscurecio las pantallas

Tags: xamarin.forms

ejecué el proyecto en visual 2019 y ahora me aparece asi anteriormente lo estaba ejecutando en vs 2017 y salia el fondo blanco, todo el proyecto se me oscurecio el fondo no se que hacer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seguramente estas ejecutando una vista con Rg plugins y podes configurar el fondo como queres que se vean cuando ejecutas la vista

Comment: Voy a revisar lo que dices, porque me cambio todo el proyecto gracias